# Using renderWith() to render core template with custom layout

Tags: php, templates, silverstripe

I have a class

```
class ModuleController extends Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array( 
        'index'
    );

    public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        return $this->renderWith(array("Module/HomePage", "Page"));
    }
}
```

And two templates, one is `Page.ss` and another is `Layout/Module/Homepage.ss`. In `Page.ss` I have a bunch of html and `$Layout`. Looking through other areas online I would have expected the page to render according to `Page.ss` and the layout variable to render with `Layout/Module/HomePage.ss` however it just renders with `Page.ss`. How can I get my page to render with the base template of `Page.ss` and render the `$Layout` with my controller defined layout?

**EDIT**

So if I put the `Homepage.ss` up one level (i.e. no 'Module' directory) this code works. Is it possible to have directories in the Layout directory as I think this folder will get messy overtime without some structure. It also seems strange that the folder path works when setting the template but not the layout.

**EDIT 2**

[Looks like](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/4738) This is a core problem I've just discovered a different way and looks to be addressed in SS4 so looks like this can't be done in SS3.

Comment: Looking at the doco deeper, the array that can be passed to renderWith simply looks for the first usable template, not a template / layout combo. Is there a way I can do this?